# Timezone bug on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I had posted this question last night, and it still tells me that it was posted `today`. Most probably because, in the time zone of Stack Overflow web server, the day hasn't changed since. I'm in the [IST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Standard_Time) time zone (GMT+05:30).

[image: It says today when the question was posted yesterday]

Comment: afaik "today" means posted in the last 24 hours.

Comment: :D Funny interpretation

Comment: @Floern, BTW [Google says this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=define+today)

Comment: its more funny for programmers, if post 5 mins ago says yesterday.

Comment: yeah! It can even say last year for a minute ago post. It's about being right or being not funny.

Comment: There are so many down votes. It is fine if they don't think of it as a bug. But is there anyone who see it as wrongly reproduced or thinks it cannot be reproduce.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All times on Stack Overflow are in UTC.

Comment: Thanks for reply. If so, then why is it saying `today` even now? Hasn't the day changed in UTC yet? .........It has

Comment: The relative time indicator will say `today` while the post has been posted less than 24 hours ago.

Comment: Fine if you or stackoverflow team or stackexchange team thinks so. But it is unintuitive for users

Comment: @IsmailS it's just fine here, I don't see the problem at all:)

Comment: That does seem weird. If you post a question at 4pm, then load it up at 3pm the next day, it will say it was posted "today"?

Comment: Except in chat, where they're translated to absolute local times.